# how to change UI Button shape programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I have a button that contains a finger print image like the picture above. that fingerPrint button has a function to segue to  viewController2. that fingerPrint button exists on the viewController1.

when the viewController1 is opened for the first time, I will get a data from the server, if I don't have that data, I shouldn't segue to viewController2 .

but sometimes we have an error as the response of my request. if I get the error response, then I want that finger button to be rectangular button that has 'Refresh' as the title and has different function to make  request again to the server

[image]

how to achieve change the shape of existing UI Button?

```
class ViewController1 : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         getDataFromServer()


    }



    @IBAction func fingerPrintButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {



    }






    func getDataFromServer() {
         // send request to get data from server
     }



}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want to animate this change? Then the question is - are you using auto layout or not?

Comment: Did you google "How to programmatically change width, height, color and text of button in swift".

Comment: "if I get the error response"  Nobody even knows what sort of  error message you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually best to do it either all in code or all in storyboard. To do it in storyboard I suggest one of the following:

- Create 2 buttons and in code hide one or another depending on your state
- Assign different images and texts for different button states (there is a dropdown in interface builder) and then change the state of a button in runtime

To do it in code overall I suggest simply changing the values.

Assume you have something like this:

```
enum ViewState {
    case idle
    case success
    case failed
}
var state: ViewState = .idle {
    didSet {
        refreshButton()
    }
}
```

Now you can set your state when you get a response or on any event needed. All you need to implement is `refreshButton`.

```
func refreshButton() {
    switch state {
        case .idle:
        button.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
        button.setImage(fingerprintImage, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .clear
        case .success:
        button.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
        button.setImage(fingerprintImage, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .clear
        case .failed:
        button.setTitle("REFRESH", for: .normal)
        button.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .green
    }
}
```

You can then use the same switch inside your button action (on press).

Answer (score 0):

```
if isError
{
    button.type = .system
    button.backgroundColor - UIColor.green
    button.setTitle("REFRESH" for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(--------)
}
else
{
    button.type = .custom
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "yourImageName.png") for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(--------)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution** is : Use two buttons one for figure Image second for Refresh text. And use button isHidden property vice-versa.

**For Auto layout**

If you are using Auto layout then use constraint `IBOutlet` and change it's `constant` property value. it will change your button height or width.

**For Auto resize**
if you are using Auto resize than you can change you button frame which you want